# Created a login form with a local SQL database, upon execution and after a login attempt an "ArgumentException Unhandled" error occurs

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, login-control, argumentexception

I understand the same thing has been asked before and closed due to a simple typo. From what I can see I don't have any typos and I've tried to figure out the problem by Googling but no luck.

I have created this Login Window. 
[Main Login Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXBrp.jpg)

I have created a local SQL Database from within Visual Studio (2015) to store my users. To establish the connection to this database I have written this line of code in my Enter button that is visible in the Main Login Window.

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=C: \USERS\NIKOS\DESKTOP\NIKOS();\SAFE BOX\DATABASE\SAFEBOXDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
```

This path has been pasted by right clicking my database and selecting properties. In the properties there is a field named Connection String. That's what I have copied and pasted, into the above path in the code.

This is all my code.

```
        //Find path for SQL Connection
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\NIKOS\DESKTOP\NIKOS();\SAFE BOX\DATABASE\SAFEBOXDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
        //Add query for actions to be taken once connection is established, select the user
        string sqlQuery = "Select * from dbo.Table Where username = '" + txtEnterUserName.Text.Trim() + "' and password = '" + txtEnterPassword.Text.Trim();
        //Add SQL Data Adapter passing in the connection and the query
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, sqlConn);

        //Create new Datatable object
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        //Fill SQL Data Adapter with the dataTable
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            loginMain objFormMain = new loginMain();
            this.Hide();
            UserDashboard userDash = new UserDashboard();
            userDash.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check Username and Password");
        }
```

When I run the program, my Main Login Window appears as it's the main window, I enter my credentials as per the table in the database and I get this error as soon as I press the "Enter" button.

[ArgumentException was unhandled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz2ol.jpg)

I have checked and rechecked the path but I can't seem to get it working and I have no idea what the problem is. General Google searches have not helped.

Due to low reputation as I am a new user, I cannot upload my table data, I only have one row with a user name and a password. Presume these are being typed correctly.

The error says that a keyword is not supported. I can't seem to understand this.

EDIT. I have reinstalled the server and the new path is now

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nikos\Documents\SafeBox.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
```

as per the new Connection String. So the new code for the Enter button is now

```
private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlQuery = @"Select * from dbo.Table 
                Where username = @user AND 
                      password = @pass";
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nikos\Documents\SafeBox.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEnterUserName.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEnterPassword.Text.Trim();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    loginMain objFormMain = new loginMain();
                    this.Hide();
                    UserDashboard userDash = new UserDashboard();
                    userDash.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Check Username and Password");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The new error I have is {"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'."} and the error points to this line.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

Comment: Please copy the text of the exception into your question rather than a link to a picture of it.

Comment: You haven't closed the opening quote around the password. But use parameterized queries rather than concatenating text, to protect against SQL injection and other benefits.

Comment: but my path does have the @ symbol at the beginning of the string. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a semicolon in the actual path to your database? I think that is causing the trouble. If you look at your exception text it is giving you the bad keyword starting after the `NIKOS();` part of your path.

Comment: NIKOS(); is the name of the folder it resides in. Just me being wierd using names like that. Semi colons are present in the path yes. I have literally copied it and pasted it.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Otherwise, try `[NIKOS()]`. Better to never use parens in folder names.

Comment: Boy have I learnt my lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many errors in your code.

The first one is the space between the C: drive letter and the remaining path is wrong and should be removed. Also adding a semicolon in the middle of the connection string as part of the path confuses the connectionstring parser that uses the semicolon as separator between keys and values. This is the origin of the error message because after the NIKOS(); semicolon the parser ends its discover of the path and tries to make sense of *\SAFE BOX....* as it was a key to parse.
You should remove it from your disk path and adjust your connectionstring

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
      Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\NIKOS\DESKTOP\NIKOS\SAFE BOX\DATABASE\SAFEBOXDB.MDF;
       Integrated Security=True;
       Connect Timeout=30;
       Encrypt=False;
       TrustServerCertificate=True;
       ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
       MultiSubnetFailover=False");
```

Now the problems in code are even worse

```
string sqlQuery = @"Select * from [Table] 
                    Where username = @user AND 
                          password = @pass";
using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
{
     sqlConn.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEnterUserName.Text.Trim();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEnterPassword.Text.Trim();

     using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
         if(reader.HasRows)
         {
              loginMain objFormMain = new loginMain();
              this.Hide();
              UserDashboard userDash = new UserDashboard();
              userDash.Show();
         }
         else
         {
              MessageBox.Show("Check Username and Password");
         }
    }
}
```

First of all, you don't need a complex SqlDataAdapter if you just want to check if the user exists or not. A simple SqlCommand with an SqlDataReader will do just fine.
Second, all disposable objects should go inside an using statement to be sure that when you have finished to use them, they will be destroyed also in case of exceptions.

Finally, parameters are always the way to go when you need to pass values to your database. Failing to use them will lead to Sql Injection attacks or unexpected syntax errors when your strings contains single quotes.

Comment: You modified OPs path, which did include both parens and a semicolon. I believe they can be escaped by enclosing the value in `{<PathWithSemicolon>}`, although I think the better approach is to not name folders with a semicolon, that leads to all kinds of problems with all kinds of things.

Comment: That's noobs for you. I have changed the folders name, I have deleted the (); and left it as Nikos. Now Visual Studio still has the Nikos(); Any ideas on how to edit that?

Comment: You should fix the connectionstring to match the existant path. What do you mean with _VS still has the Nikos();_

Comment: The Connection String for my database that holds the table, is still referring to Nikos(); I have changed the name of this folder to Nikos and the database no longer connects. I cannot edit the Connection String.

Comment: The connection string is in the code above, just inside the constructor call to SqlConnection. You can edit it and adjust to the new path.

Comment: I have removed the (); from the folder. The disk path is now C:\Users\Nikos\Desktop\Nikos\Safe Box\Database. All I need is to alter the connection string and I think it'll be OK. I can't find how to alter the connection string. MSDN isn't much help at the moment. I'm checking there too.

Comment: Where is this connectionstring that you can't change? What is the name of the window where you see the database with the now wrong database?

Comment: OK. I've altered the code accordingly. The problem now is that my database in my SQL Server Explorer has an X on it. No connection can be established.

Comment: Just drop the old one and recreate the connection with the new information as you have done initially. (Right Click, Delete) and then (Right Click, Add over the DataConnection group)

Comment: Done. Now I have this error. {"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'."} and its pointing to this line using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

Comment: There's definitely something going with the server. I'll look into it and I'll get back to close the question. Thanks

Comment: Do you really have a table in your database named _Table_? Table is a reserved keyword and you shouldn't use these keywords for your database names. If you can change it better, if you can't change it then use square brackets around that name _SELECT * FROM [TABLE]...._

Comment: That was it Steve. I needed to do [TABLE]. Works perfectly. Many Thanks.